# .htaccess rewrite rule to external domain - client IP and HTTP referer

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

let's say i'm running a web site at www.**domain1**.com

in ".htaccess" i do a redirect to an external "**domain2**" as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^mydirectory/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/mydirectory/$1 [NC,L]
```

note that in the RewriteRule i'm *not* passing the flags `[R]` or `[R=301]`.

and now i'm opening http://www.domain1.com/mydirectory/ from a web browser.

in the logs of that external "domain2", what exactly will show up as:

- client IP
- HTTP referrer (referer)

will the client IP be from the actual client web browser, or from my web server running at "domain1"?
will there be any hints that it got "redirected" from my "domain1"? in the "referer" field, for example?

and will the web client will be notified about any "redirection" status code?

Comment: Why don't you simply try things and find out the answer yourself?

Comment: @arkascha: because i'm a beginner. because i don't have two domains. and even if i tested locally, i wouldn't know how this behaves "in general" - with different web servers. that's why i'm asking how the concept is supposed to be working as per the standards. and finally, because SO is for asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the client IP be from the actual client web browser, or from my web server running at "domain"?

The "actual client web browser". (Or, whatever IP would normally be reported when that client makes a request to `domain2.com`, as they could be connecting through a proxy server, VPN, etc.)

A redirect response from `domain1.com` is an instruction for the client to make an entirely new request to `domain2.com`.

> will there be any hints that it got "redirected" from my "domain1"? in the "referer" field, for example?

Not if you make the redirect as soon as the user first arrives at `domain1.com`. Generally, the *browser* preserves the `Referer` header from the previous "non-redirected" request. The redirect itself does not generate a `Referer`.

So, if you make a direct request to `domain1.com` (ie. no `Referer`) then no `Referer` will be passed in the redirected request to `domain2.com`.

However, if a user followed a link from `another-domain.com` to `domain1.com` (ie. `another-domain.com` is the `Referer`) and you issue a "redirect" from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com` then the *browser* would pass `another-domain.com` as the `Referer` (by default).

And if you allowed the user to browse `domain1.com` for a while (navigating from page to page - which will naturally generate a `Referer`) before issuing a redirect to `domain2.com` then `domain1.com` will likely be seen as the `Referer` when the client makes the request to `domain2.com`. At least, by default, this can be overridden by setting a [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) (in modern browsers) on the referring site.

Of course, the user may have configured their browser to suppress the `Referer` and the originating website (eg. `another-domain.com`, or `domain1.com`) can also suppress the `Referer` being sent by setting a [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) in modern browsers. Old browsers (such as IE11) do not support this, so you are at the mercy of whatever defaults the browser uses.

> and will the web client will be notified about any "redirection" status code?

Yes, that's what a redirect is.

If `domain1.com` redirects to `domain2.com` then...

1. `domain1.com` sends a 3xx redirect response back to the client with a `Location` HTTP response header telling the client of the URL to make a request to.
2. The client's browser then makes a new request to the URL stated in the `Location` header.

---

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^mydirectory/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/mydirectory/$1 [NC,L]
> ```

Note that this generates a 302 (temporary) redirect, even though the status code (`R` or `R=301`) is not explicitly stated. (The `RewriteBase` directive is entirely superfluous here.)